# How to split the cell with user condition like "\t and \n" in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-query

**My data looks like this:**

Customer Name:\tAAA \n\n Customer Email:\tAAA@b.com \n\n Customer Mobile:\t12456788 \n\n Customer Message:\n\n\taaabbbcccmessage

**I want to convert the data like:**

AAA AAA@b.com 12456788 aaabbbcccmessage in separate cell.

***I tried this formula but not working:***

> ARRAYFORMULA(split(join(":",index(split(C16,":"),1,1),index(split(C16,":"),1,2),index(split(C16,":"),1,3),index(split(C16,":"),1,4)),":"))

***Error occurred:***

> arrayformula(split(join(index(split(C16,"Customer
>   Name:\t")),index(split(C16,"Customer Email:\t")))))

Comment: What's the name of the error? You have a history of abandoning threads too. Provide your dummy copy of the sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this formula as starting point:

`=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(B35,"\\t|\\n","$"),"$",1)`

- replace repeating parts of string with `$`
- split the result by `$`